# RecyclerView behaves strangely inside ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I struggled with a visual bug in my `RecyclerView` until I noticed that it's caused by putting my `RecyclerView` into a `ConstraintLayout`.

This is what I tried to achieve (`RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` inside `LinearLayout`):

[image]

And that was my first attempt (`RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` inside `ConstraintLayout`):

[image]

So my question is: **Why aren't the `RecyclerView` items aligend properly when the `RecyclerView` lives within a `ConstraintLayout`?**

A look with the Layout Inspector yields that the `RecyclerView` does cover the whole screen width.

Also, the items are layed out as expected when assigning `wrap_content` or `match_parent` to the item's `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`.

For example, when both are set to `wrap_content` this is the result in the `ConstraintLayout`:

[image]

Here is the source for the broken layout (second screenshot).

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.recyclerviewtest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyRecyclerViewAdapter());
    }
}
```

**MyRecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.recyclerviewtest;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_item, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="GridLayoutManager"
        app:spanCount="2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**recycler_view_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LINE 1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LINE 2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

To summarize: The layout only breaks when setting a fixed value to `android:layout_width` or `android:layout_height` while using a `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: maybe this link can help https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/understanding-androids-layoutinflater-inflate/.

Comment: I read that blog entry some days ago. But I'll look at it again. Maybe I forgot something that could help me here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set your recycler view width to 0dp, add a contraint startToStarOf parent and a contraint endToEndOf parent too. Also, add a contraint horizontalWeight to 1.

Let me know it works.

Comment: Yeah, that results in the correct result. But why are the items aligned the way they are although the `RecyclerView` spans the whole screen width?

Comment: @rewgoes same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46282188/recyclerview-behaves-strangely-inside-constraintlayout) for me but this solution not working. Help please!